# EMF figures with latex text from Python - Renderer error

Tags: python, latex, .emf

I need to produce some figures from data, using python. It has to have Latex text in labels, legend and title, while output format must be .emf (Encapsulated Metafile, readable in M$ Word).

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import pretty_print as pp, latex
import os
ion()

close('all')

rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
matplotlib.pyplot.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rc('xtick',  labelsize = 12);
matplotlib.rc('ytick',  labelsize = 12);
matplotlib.rc('legend', fontsize  = 12);

A = loadtxt('Data.txt', unpack=True)

p1, = plot(A[0,:],A[1,:])

xlabel('time [s]', fontsize=14)
ylabel('Current i_1 [A]',fontsize=14)
title('Phase current',fontsize=14)
legend([p1],['i_1'], frameon=True, loc='upper right')
grid(True)
savefig('data.emf')
```

Errors are like this: "**RendererEMF instance has no attribute**". Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a missing link between the matplotlib.textpath module. You can solve this by editing the file [path to python libs]/matplotlib/backends/backend_emf.py. In the header of this file add the line

```
from matplotlib import textpath
```

In the class definition of the class RendererEMF add the line

```
self._text2path = textpath.TextToPath()
```

in the **init** method. This fixed latex rendering in emf at least for me.